# Debugging Webfont Issues

Tags: css, fonts, webfonts

For the past couple of hours, I have been trying to decipher why I can't get specific webfonts to load correctly on [my site](https://cpugrade.com/).

## Google Fonts

I am using the `.WOFF2` format. The two fonts in question, are [Exo 2](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Exo+2) for headings, and [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) for body text. I have been debugging in the latest versions of Opera<sup>`1`</sup>, Chrome<sup>`2`</sup> and Firefox<sup>`3`</sup>; all of which support the `.WOFF2` format, but none of them load the fonts. I am thinking there is an error in my CSS somewhere. The thing is, I have compared it to [Google's provided code](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Exo%202) and it appears to match. For the record, Opera is my default native browser, and the one I am using to type this question.

On my server, I have the font files obtained from Google Fonts stored inside my script assets folder. They were renamed for a more developer-friendly name (I'm not sure if this is what's giving me the problems?).

```
(Google Fonts)
https://cpugrade.com/a/s/exo-2-regular.woff2
https://cpugrade.com/a/s/open-sans-regular.woff2
```

Here is the CSS that I tried for Google Fonts<sup>`4`</sup>:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "Exo 2";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Exo 2'), local('Exo2-Regular'), url('exo-2-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}
@font-face {
    font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans Regular'), local('OpenSans-Regular'), url('open-sans-regular.woff2') format('woff2');
}

body { 
    font-family: "Open Sans", "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
body #content .section h1,
body #content .section h2 {
    font-family: "Exo 2", Ubuntu, "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

## Font Squirrel

Additionally, while debugging, I decided to try a different format, so I went to [Font Squirrel](https://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/exo-2) and downloaded the `.WOFF` format. I didn't rename the font file, and uploaded it straight to my server and I copied over the CSS code provided. Interestingly, this actually worked. I feel I should point out that I didn't try both Exo 2 methods simultaneously.

```
(Font Squirrel)
https://cpugrade.com/a/s/Exo2-Regular-webfont.woff
```

Lastly, here is the CSS from Font Squirrel:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "exo_2regular";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url('Exo2-Regular-webfont.woff') format('woff');
}

body #content .section h1,
body #content .section h2 {
    font-family: "exo_2regular", Ubuntu, "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

## Notes

1. Opera version `46.0.2597.57 (PGO)`.
2. Chrome version `60.0.3112.90 (Official Build) (64-bit)`.
3. Firefox version `54.0.1 (64-bit)`.
4. I can confirm that using the `@import` method from Google Fonts works, however I would preferably like to host locally.

Comment: Move your scripts into the head where they belong.

Comment: @Rob Hello, I am not sure where that conclusion came from, because all of them are inside my `<head>` tags?

Comment: You have two script elements between the head and the body. Probably not related to the problem, though.

Comment: @Rob Gotcha. I was probably following Google's requests a little too much there.